# Make the same table using Python cvs module

Tags: python, csv, originlab

I'm working on a project, comaring different sorting algorithms. I already have a data generating script, which can time everything. I need this data to fit in a table (I'm using OriginPro 8) like that one:
[image: Origin Table]
But what should I write in Python script, so when I import .csv file it would look like this exact table?

Right now I have this structure:

```
{'bubble_sort': {'BEST': {'COMP': 999000, 'PERM': 0, 'TIME': 1072.061538696289},
             'RND': {'COMP': 999000,
                     'PERM': 249853,
                     'TIME': 1731.0991287231445},
             'WORST': {'COMP': 999000,
                       'PERM': 499500,
                       'TIME': 2358.1347465515137}},
'hoare_sort': {'BEST': {'COMP': 10975, 'PERM': 0, 'TIME': 14.000654220581055},  #and so on
```

And this code to save it:

```
def write_csv_in_file(fn, data):
with open(fn + ".cvs", 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for key, value in data.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

And after importing get this table:
[image: Bad table]
And it is far away from the variant I need.

What I want is that:

let's say that this data was collected on best case array of length 100. Then for 1st row of first table there should be values from `['bubble_sort']['BEST']['TIME']`, `['hoare_sort']['BEST']['TIME']` and so on. Then I'd make the same tables for worst case scenario (`["WORST"]`), random (`["RND"]`), and then repeat everything for number of comparissons (`["COMP"]`) and permutations done (`["PERM"]`)

Comment: How would you get from the data you have given to the exact table you have given? Please show what your output should look like for the data you have given.